# How do I get input from JTextField from other panels

Tags: java, swing, textarea

I am new to using JTextFields and was curious on how to get input from 3 different panels. The panels will take numbers from inputs and average the scores. For that, I want to access all 3 panels to do the math. I have a panel for three different people's scores that I want to average. So I would like to get mattsTotalScore and add it with timsTotalScore and BensTotalScore and make the average appear after a button on a fourth panel.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MattPanel extends JPanel {

    public MattPanel(){
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 250;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Matt's Scores"));

        JLabel memMatt = new JLabel("MEMORABILITY :");
        JTextField textMemMattPane = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel comMatt = new JLabel("COMPOSITION :");
        JTextField textComMattPane = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel mixMatt = new JLabel("MIX/MASTER :");
        JTextField textMixMattPane = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel soundMatt = new JLabel("SOUND DESIGN :");
        JTextField textSoundMattPane = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel enjoyMatt = new JLabel("ENJOYMENT :");
        JTextField textEnjoyMattPane = new JTextField(10);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        ///First Column ///////////////////////
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gc.weightx = 0.5; gc.weighty = 0.5;
        gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 0;
        add(memMatt, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 1;
        add(comMatt, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 2;
        add(mixMatt, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 3;
        add(soundMatt, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 4;
        add(enjoyMatt, gc);

        //Second Column //////////////////////
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 0;
        add(textMemMattPane,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 1;
        add(textComMattPane,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 2;
        add(textMixMattPane,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 3;
        add(textSoundMattPane,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 4;
        add(textEnjoyMattPane,gc);
    }
}
```

Comment: the way you do it, you can't. all your fields are local fields. declare them on class level, and you can create setters for them and for their values

Comment: ah okay, that makes sense. I'll give it a try

Comment: `..MattPanel extends JPanel` Don't extend GUI components unless actually necessary. It leads to conundrums just like this.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the `getComponents()` method from JPanel to get all components, although you would have to somehow identify the TextFields like:

```java
MattPanel panel = new MattPanel();
int sum = 0;
int nr = 0;
for(Component comp : panel.getComponents()){
    if(comp instanceof JTextField){ 
        String text = ((JTextField)comp).getText();
        sum += Integer.parseInt(text);
        nr ++;
    }
}
double avg = sum/nr;
```

Comment: This is an hack to try & account for a bad design. The fix is to be had by fixing the design.